# Why "arr" can not be GC?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

```js
(() => {
  var arr = [];  // Memory leak 
  for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    arr.push(Math.random());
  }

  function emptyFn() {}
  function invoke(options) {
    window.__options = options;
  }

  (() => {
    emptyFn(arr)
  })()

  invoke({
    success: () => {},
    fail: () => {},
  });
})();
```

I run this code in Chrome, See the memory useage in devTools, the var arr never been GC

Comment: I don't know why, i think it should only keep window.__options

Comment: Garbage collection is generally *reactive*, not *proactive*. The array can be collected, but it won't be until the runtime decides to do so.

Comment: I try to click garbage collection button on the chrome devtools，still not. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arr` is in the closure of the function `success` which you pass to `invoke` and which is therefore accessible as `window.__options.success`. Imagine that the function body `success` wasn't empty but

```js
success: () => {
  console.log(arr.length);
}
```

Then the command `window.__options.success()` must return `10000000` even after the code from your question has been executed in Chrome.

I assume that the garbage collector does not analyze which parts of its closure a function actually accesses but assumes that it might access everything in it.

If you define a function

```js
function noop() {}
```

and assign *that* to `success` and `fail`

```js
invoke({
  success: noop,
  fail: noop
});
```

the `arr` can be collected.

Interstingly, the big array is also collected if you remove the `emptyFn` call. In this case the garbage collector seems to recognize that `arr` occurs nowhere after the first four lines and can therefore be immediately forgotten after these four lines. If you replace the `emptyFn` call statement with the statement `debugger`, you will see `arr = undefined` in the debugger.

Comment: This could be true, though the *actual* functions returned do not contain any references to the `arr` symbol, so it remains the case that `arr` cannot possibly be referenced when the IIFE completes. (The returned functions cannot be modified or extended to reference `arr`, in other words.)

Comment: I believe that the GC does not carry out such an analysis, see my augmented answer.

Comment: Again, certainly could be true, though given all the incredible things that V8 (for example) does for optimization, that would be somewhat surprising. In particular, concluding that a function with an empty body won't reference anything in the closure would be comparatively easy.

Comment: But I repeat that I acknowledge it's entirely possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but when i remove the emptyFn call in IIFE, arr can be GC. I'm confused again .